# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'analytics ' en servicio de angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un servicio en un proyecto angular donde tengo clases con codigos para registrar eventos etc.. en segment.io
I aveces me compila bien pero aveces me da el siguiente error.

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'analytics'
```

os dejo una muestra del servicio con las clases de tracking haber si alguien sabe como arreglar el error.

```html
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../models/User';

@Injectable()
export class TrackingService{

  public url: string;
  public identify: any;

  constructor(
    public _http: HttpClient
  ){

  }

  //page tracking
  pageTracking(page){
    analytics.page('page', {
      name: 'page',
    });
  }
  loginTracking(){
    analytics.track('Logged In');
  }

  //Login & user tracking
  authIdentity(identity){
    analytics.identify(identity.sub, {
      name: identity.name,
      email: identity.email,
      role: identity.role,
      logins: 1
    });
  }

  //call to action Tracking
  //booking tracking
  //buy tracking

}
```

Comment: No tienes un objeto `analytics` declarado en ninguna parte, esa variable no existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando una librería que no tiene tipos declarados para typescript (puedes buscar en http://definitelytyped.org/), tienes que declarar la variable como *global*, para que el compilador asuma que existe. Crea un fichero en la raíz de tu código fuente llamado `globals.d.ts` y añade la sentencia:

```
declare var analytics: any;
```

Comment: y donde tendría que poner código? en el contructor?

Comment: He editado para dejarlo más claro